# Обособление запятой «как не родной»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, оборот-с-как

А что ты застыл в дверях(,) как не родной?

Не пойму, входит ли оборот в состав сказуемого или нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос № 296544
Здравствуйте, нужна ли запятая перед фразой "как неродной": *Что стоишь, как неродной?* Или это фразеологизм и запятая не требуется?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Постановка запятой уместна.

В вашем примере при изъятии оборота смысл совсем не нарушается. Значит, не входит в сказуемое. Здесь имеет место сравнение (запятая), а не отождествление с неродным (без запятой):
*А что ты застыл в дверях (так), как не родной?*

Answer (score 2):

> В предложении **со сравнительным оборотом тоже нужна запятая.** Такие обороты всегда имеют образную окраску, сопоставляют какой-то признак предмета с другим.
>
> Союз «как» можно заменить словом «подобно»:
>
> *Метель выла за окном, как дикий зверь. = Метель выла за окном, подобно
> дикому зверю.
> Обида, как острый нож, пронзила ее сердце. = Обида,
> подобно острому ножу, пронзила ее сердце.*
>
> (...)
>
> Запятая перед «как» НЕ ставится в следующих случаях:
>
> (...)
>
> Случай 2. Если оборот с союзом «как» **входит в состав сказуемого и
> неразрывно связан с ним по смыслу.** Как и в случае с фразеологизмами,
> предложение без этого оборота будет бессмысленным:
>
> *Мы ждали первых отчетов о росте поведенческих факторов и сидели как на иголках.
> Она поставила себя как хозяйка.*
>
> https://petr-panda.ru/zapyataya-pered-kak-pravila/

Это именно наш случай: *А что ты застыл в дверях, подобно неродному?* *А что ты застыл в дверях?* — нигде никакой бессмыслицы. (Кстати, думаю, «неродной» здесь следует писать слитно:

> Слово «родной» напишем отдельно от частицы «не», если в тексте есть
> противопоставление с союзом «а» или слова, усиливающие отрицание.
>
> Примеры предложений.
>
> *Тимур мне вовсе не родной брат.*
>
> *Ольга мне не родной человек, а посторонний.*
>
> В оставшихся случаях пишем слово «неродной» слитно.
>
> Примеры предложений.
>
> *Артем неродной сын Анжелы.*
>
> *Что стоишь в стороне, как будто неродной мне человек?*
>
> https://portalonline.ru/russkij-yazyk/2919-kak-pishetsya-nerodnoj-ili-ne-rodnoj.html)

Comment: Похоже на то, но в Нацкорпусе 12/10 в пользу слитного.

Comment: Тут стоит говорить не о том, как лучше (слитно или вместе) — что внизу ответа, а о том, что "как не родной" вообще ошибка. То есть о правописании частицы "не" в сравнениях. Структура: *как кто, как тот-то*, а не *как не кто, как не тот-то*. Это сложная тема, и, может, такого вообще нет в правилах.

Answer (score 1):

С запятой я согласна, а вот с пояснениями не совсем. Ответ можно дать очень краткий:

Устойчивый сравнительный оборот «как неродной»  в предложении заданной структуры обособляется, так как  в этом случае ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНА  постановка двух логических ударений: *А что ты застыл **в дверЯх,** **как нероднОй**?*

Произнести все предложение как единую фразу с одним ударением и повышением голоса **при вопросе** на последнем слове сложнее.

Но при изменении структуры предложения  оборот может не обособляться: *А что ты застыл в дверях *как нероднОй,* проходи в кОмнату.*

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Как обычно рассуждают при решении подобных задач? Какое значение имеет оборот (сравнение, тождество), входит ли он в сказуемое или нет (он как неродной, он стал как неродной), можно ли оборот изъять из предложения без нарушения смысла?

Но ведь оборот с союзом КАК  может быть не только сказуемым, но и необособленным обстоятельством (*стоит как неродной*).

Кроме того, один и тот же оборот в разных предложениях может обособляться или не обособляться. Вот классический пример: Тропинка вьется как змея. – Тропинка, как змея, вьется среди камней.

2. Это касается и оборотов **«как неродной», «как чужой».** В художественной литературе есть разные примеры. Можно также отметить, что  по-разному оформляются одни и те же сочетания:

А то жмЕшься, как нероднОй.

Руки он никому не подАл, вошел как чужОй.

Что теперь стоИшь, как нероднОй?

Повстречались, а он не узнАл ее и сидел около нее как чужОй.

Ну что ты как нерОдной сидишь?

3. Что здесь очевидно? При обособлении ставятся **два ударения** – на обороте и на предыдущем слове, тогда можно сделать паузу и обозначить ее запятой. Но если  структура предложения и позиция оборота таковы, что ставится только **одно ударение** (интонация простого предложения), то оборот не обособляется. Это мы видим на практике, в реальных текстах. **Нельзя делать вид, что этого нет, и искать ответы  только в правилах.**

ПРИМЕЧАНИЯ

1. Сложно ли понять такое решение? Сделать это мешает обычный **консерватизм** в виде привычки к формальным (чисто грамматическим или семантическим) рассуждениям. Мы не очень-то привыкли учитывать  интонационно-структурную  форму предложения – вероятно, это дело будущего.  Соответственно,  следует ожидать, что в ближайшее время будут предлагаться именно такие решения, как в этой теме.
2. В данном случае желательно **слитное написание приставки НЕ** (согласно мнению Грамоты.ру):

Вопрос № 279283. В словосочетании "русский не родной" (имеется в виду язык) "не" пишется слитно или раздельно и почему?
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка.**  Как определение: русский (как) неродной. **В знач. сказуемого:** Русский не родной (= не является родным).

Прилагательное "неродной" со слитным написанием можно найти в словаре РАН, а в составе оборота "как неродной" мы имеем скорее **определительное**, а не предикативное значение.

Comment: Пример со змеёй без запятой не очень понял, может, вы делаете оборот самым главным в сообщении, но это вершина сложности в этой теме — оно всех собьёт с толку. "Застыл в дверях" самостоятельно, вхождение в это сказуемое не требуется. Мне же хотелось узнать о возможности раздельного написания в оборотах с "как" (с любым прилагательным). Что-то мне кажется, что так нельзя. Может, расскажете об этом во втором ответе (если знаете)?

Comment: Приведите пример, тогда попробую рассказать. А еще лучше вопрос задайте, обсудим на форуме, а то в комментариях сложно рассказывать.

Comment: У меня нет примеров. Есть ли у вас такой, где раздельное написание?

Comment: Попробую поискать...

Comment: Я не поверю любому примеру из литературы, потому что, например, в Нацкорпусе куча ошибок, но он очень помогает. Нужно, чтоб раздельное написание было очевидным или чтоб слитное подходило хуже, но оба должны быть возможны. Просто что-то мне кажется, что только слитное написание корректно.